# Protocols and Delegates in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have two View Controllers: "DiscoverViewController" and "LocationRequestModalViewController".

The first time a user opens the "DiscoverViewController", I overlay "LocationRequestModalViewController" which contains a little blurb about accessing the users location data and how it can help them.

On the "LocationRequestModalViewController" there are two buttons: "No thanks" and "Use location". I need to send the response from the user back to the "DiscoverViewController"

I have done some research and found that delegates/protocols are the best way to do it, so I followed a guide to get that working, but I'm left with 2 errors and can't figure them out.

The errors are:

**On DiscoverViewController**

```
'DiscoverViewController' is not convertible to 'LocationRequestModalViewController'
```

**On LocationRequestModalViewController**

```
'LocationRequestModalViewController' does not have a member name 'sendBackUserLocationDataChoice'
```

I've marked where the errors are happen in the following files:

**DiscoverViewController.swift**

```
class DiscoverViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate, LocationRequestModalViewControllerDelegate {

    func showLocationRequestModal() {
        var storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        var locationRequestVC: AnyObject! = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("locationRequestVC")
        self.presentingViewController?.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.CurrentContext
        self.tabBarController?.presentViewController(locationRequestVC as UIViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {
        let vc = segue.destinationViewController as LocationRequestModalViewController
        vc.delegate = self //This is where error 1 happens
    }

    func sendBackUserLocationDataChoice(controller: LocationRequestModalViewController, useData: Bool) {
        var enableData = useData
        controller.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        showLocationRequestModal()
    }
}
```

**LocationRequestModalViewController**

```
protocol LocationRequestModalViewControllerDelegate {
    func sendBackUserLocationDataChoice(controller:LocationRequestModalViewController,useData:Bool)
}

class LocationRequestModalViewController: UIViewController {

    var delegate:LocationRequestModalViewController? = nil

    @IBAction func dontUseLocationData(sender: AnyObject) {
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }

    @IBAction func useLocationData(sender: AnyObject) {
        delegate?.sendBackUserLocationDataChoice(self, useData: true) // This is where error #2 happens
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        //Modal appearance stuff here...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is in your question itself. Both errors tells the exact reason.

#### Issue 1

```
let vc      = segue.destinationViewController as LocationRequestModalViewController
vc.delegate = self //This is where error 1 happens
```

The self is of type `DiscoverViewController`

But you declared the delegate as:

```
var delegate:LocationRequestModalViewController? = nil
```

You need to change that to:

```
var delegate:DiscoverViewController? = nil
```

#### Issue 2

The same reason, `LocationRequestModalViewController` does not confirm to the `LocationRequestModalViewControllerDelegate`, change the delegate declaration.

Comment: Thanks, the guide I was following seemed to have it backwards, as shown in my post. Switched it out as per your instruction and the errors both went away. I'm relatively new to iOS development, so I'm still learning a lot. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You have defined your `delegate` as having type `LocationRequestModalViewController` which does not conform to `LocationRequestModalViewControllerDelegate`.

Comment: Thanks for the help! The first answer was a bit more clearly explained, but I appreciate the time!